# django urlpatterns - reverse hits wrong url

Tags: django, django-urls

I am still working with the polls app, but made a few changes to allow multiple questions to be answered on each page with a common 'submit' button. After these changes, a weird bug emerged.

view.index is a simple list of questions, with links to a link-redirect view that just captures username and then loads a page with the questions and that users data. (might not be the best way, but it was working).

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'polls/_index.html'
context_object_name = 'question_set'
def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(man_index__gte='1').order_by('man_index') 

@login_required(redirect_field_name=None) 
def qlink(request, man_index):
    user_id = request.user.username
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, man_index = int(man_index))
    page_ref = question.man_page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:page', args=(user_id, page_ref)))
```

The bug first emerged with the redirect throwing a 'user not identified' after trying to load a url that was polls//, but it had not hit the 'qlink' view at all - instead the error was coming from views.answer, the view that handles the answers.

From my urls.py:

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^qlink/(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/$', views.qlink, name='qlink'),
    url(r'^(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^analytics/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<n>[0-9]+)/$', views.analytics, name='analytics'),
    url(r'^hashtags/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.page_hashtag_detail, name='hashtags'),  
    url(r'download/$', views.write_out, name = 'download'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/pg(?P<page_num>[0-9]+)/$', views.pageView, name='page'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/$', views.answer, name='answer'),
    #url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/short_answer/', views.short_answer, name='short_answer'),
    #url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    #url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/long_answer/', views.long_answer, name='long_answer'),
    url(r'^charts/contribution$', views.contribution_chart, name='contribution_chart'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/answer_delete/', views.answer_delete, name='answer_delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\w+)/(?P<man_index>[0-9]+)/brainstorm/', views.brainstorm, name='page_brainstorm'),  
]
```

This is the link to click to get an error in index.html:

```
            {% for question in question_set %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'polls:qlink' question.man_index %}"/> {{question.man_index}}  {{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

This is the error:

```
    DoesNotExist at /polls/1/
User matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Users\cruicksa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 380
Python Executable:  C:\Users\cruicksa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['H:\\Workspace\\Django Code\\mysite6',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.1-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pdfrw-0.3-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\cruicksa\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Thu, 17 Aug 2017 04:37:15 +0000
```

Comment: According to your `urls.py`, the url `/polls/1/` hits `views.answer`, which apparently looks for the user with `id`. Now the error tells you such user does not exist. Not sure what's in `views.answer`, but you need a user matching the passed `id` there.

Comment: views.answer should not be catching a link from url polls:qlink with the only parameter being a question's manually assigned index.  It takes one parameter, a username.

Comment: update: just tried it again without any change, but after stopping and restarting the server and the browser, and it is now working.  I had tried each of those but not both together, so I will chalk this up to bad versions of templates for the time being.